# Read external file match specific string in first column and return respective string of second column in php

Tags: php, string, return, matching, vlookup

I have two text files, csvurl.txt and tickerMaster.txt 
tickerMaster.txt 
H0001

Remarks: No "H0003" in tickerMaster.txt and the number are not in sequence

csvurl.txt
H0001, URL1
H0003, URL3

I would like to read the entries in tickerMaster.txt one by one, say H0001, H0003...
and createURL by matching the data in csvurl.txt. So I am using following code...

```
<?php
  function createURL($ticker){
    $file = 'csvurl.txt';
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $sep = ',';
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $searchfor = $ticker;
    $pattern = "/^($searchfor\w+)$sep.*$/m";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo implode($matches[0])."\n";
    }
    else{
        echo "No matches found";
    }
}

function getCSVFile($url, $outputFile){
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = str_replace("Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close", "", $content);
    $content = trim($content);
    file_put_contents($outputFile, $content);
}

function fileToDatabase($txtFile, $tableName){
    $file = fopen($txtFile, "r");
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
        $pieces = explode(",", $line);

        $date = $pieces[0];
        $open = $pieces[1];
        $high = $pieces[2];
        $low = $pieces[3];
        $close = $pieces[4];
        $volume = $pieces[5];
        $amount_change = $close-$open;
        $percent_change = ($amount_change/$open)*100;


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result){
            $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (date DATE, PRIMARY KEY(date), open FLOAT, high FLOAT, low FLOAT, close FLOAT, volume INT, amount_change FLOAT, percent_change FLOAT)";
            mysql_query($sql2);
        }

        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO $tableName (date, open, high, low, close, volume, amount_change, percent_change) VALUES ('$date','$open','$high','$low','$close','$volume', '$amount_change', '$percent_change')";
        mysql_query($sql3);
    }
    fclose($file);
}


function main(){
$mainTickerFile = fopen("tickerMaster.txt", "r");
while(!feof($mainTickerFile)){
    $companyTicker = fgets($mainTickerFile);
    $companyTicker = trim($companyTicker);
    $fileURL = createURL($companyTicker);
    $companyTxtFile = "txtFiles/".$companyTicker.".txt";
    getCSVFile($fileURL, $companyTxtFile);
    fileToDatabase($companyTxtFile, $companyTicker);




    }
}
main()
?>
```

However, what I got is the whole line on the information in csvurl.txt
for example:
No matches foundH0001,URL1H0003,URL3

My desired output is just: 
URL1

Actually, I am looking for the function like vlookup in excel, but I cant search any solution for this kind of matching.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppouse data have not error, so don't do any test

```
    $c1 = file('csvurl.txt');
    $l = count($c1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        list($name,$url) = explode(',', $c1[$i]);
// making array $red['H001'] => 'URL1"
        $red[trim($name)] = trim($url);
    }
    unset($c1);
    $c = file('tickerMaster.txt');
    $l = count($c);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $c[$i] = trim($c[$i]);
// If rule exists
        if(isset($red[$c[$i]])) echo($red[$c[$i]]);
    }
```

Comment: hi, splash58, thanks for your prompt reply. How I can integrate in my code? I have replace the content in function createURL($ticker){...} and I have changed the "$name" in your code to "$ticker". I ran the code and obtain: URL1URL1. So whats wrong in my code? Thanks.

Comment: test your files and echos. i'm sure

Comment: Splash58, I have upload all my code here. Eventually, I re-add the H0003 tickerMaster.txt to test the code. I found I can only get the data for H0001 only but not H0003. That is, every text file create by php code only show the data for H0001. Would you please kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: I'll be back in an hour

Comment: At least, swap these to lines:     `$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $searchfor = $ticker;`

Comment: What is the meaning of swap these to lines?? see my following answer, I don't know how to write the code again. Should I edit the original file in order to make you clear? or I should put the new code in the answer section?

Comment: Write `$searchfor = $ticker; $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/'); ` because you usung var before initiation

Comment: I've change fucntion code. I hope you see edit. Take and, i think, delete your answer - it not a place for code exchange :)

Comment: hi Splash, I am trying. Let me answer tonight.

Comment: `return isset($red[$ticker]) ? return($red[$ticker]) : false;` seems wrong. second `return` in the line is syntax error, unexpected `return` and `:` is another syntax error unexpected `:`

Comment: Oh, yes. remove it. return isset($red[$ticker]) ? $red[$ticker] : false;